# Passing absent parameters

Tags: ruby

I have seen a particular code smell with default parameters. That is when a method has a default value set for one of its params but the caller passes `nil` instead of passing no value. In most cases, this is because the caller has a hash and it tries to pass a particular value from the hash. Specifically:

```
def foo(params)
  ...
  bar(params[:first], params[:second]) # :second doesn't exist
end

def bar(first, second = 2)
end
```

The second param to `foo` doesn't not become the default value but becomes `nil`. The most common way I have seen this handled is that the first line within the function bar is:

```
second ||= 2
```

Is there a better way of handling this? That is, whenever `nil` or no param gets passed, assign a default value.

Answer (score 11):

```
def bar(first, second = 2)
```

This sets `second` to `2` if the argument omitted. `nil` is a value with a meaning, so passing `nil` as the value for argument is explicitly telling it to be `nil`. This is on purpose, so you can override the default with `nil` if you want.

If you want your argument to assign a default if it is omitted or `nil`, then `||=` is the idiomatic way to do it.

```
def bar(first, second = nil)
  second ||= 2
  puts second
end

bar 1      #=> 2
bar 1, 3   #=> 3
bar 1, nil #=> 2
```

the `second = nil` allows you to omit the argument, and assigns a default of `nil`. And if the argument is `nil` you can set it to a real default.  This means that passing in `nil` and omitting the argument is now essentially the same thing.

It doesn't behave this way universally because sometime you *want* to replace a default argument with `nil`.  And the way default arguments works allows you to do just that.